# How can I hide one tab of SlidingTab layout?

Tags: android, android-tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have a SlidingTabLayout with 2 Tabs. I am launching this screen from two activities. While launching from one activity , I need only first tab to be visible. Is it possible to hide one specific tab of SlidingTabLayout?

Comment: setCurrentItem() for viewPager and setVisibility(View.GONE) for tab to hide the tab and

Answer (score 0):

You may use `setVisibility(View.GONE)` for the tab